# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getpreReady" (Twig & Symfony3)

Tags: php, templates, twig, symfony

I encountered the problem suggested in the title, using Twig. The exact error is the following : 
`Attempted to call an undefined method named "getpreReady" of class "__TwigTemplate_9583a7109672ac89ad8f73f6abf919dbeb71998598a2a1a4613d3457606a7304".`

This happens when using macros. Here is my calling template :

```
{% extends 'MRPlatformBundle:Full/AbstractForm:form.html.twig' %}

{% set isSenior = (type=='logeur(se)') ? true : false %}

{%use 'MRPlatformBundle:Common/Person/addForm:addFormBlocks.html.twig'%}
{%import 'MRPlatformBundle:Common/Person/addForm:addFormMacros.html.twig' as common %}

{%block CSSexterne%}
    {{parent()}}
    {{common.CSSexterne()}}
{%endblock%}

{%block JSexterne%}
    {{parent()}}
    {{common.JSexterne()}}
{%endblock%}

{%block preReady%}
    {{parent()}}
    {{common.preReady()}}
{%endblock%}
```

and here are the lines of the macros-file :

```
{% macro CSSexterne() %}
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{{ asset('CSS-JS/TimePicki-master/css/timepicki.css') }}"/>
  <link href="{{asset('CSS-JS/jQueryFiler/css/jquery.filer.css')}}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="{{asset('CSS-JS/jQueryFiler/css/themes/jquery.filer-dragdropbox-theme.css')}}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="{{asset('CSS-JS/slim/slim/slim.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endmacro %}

{% macro JSexterne() %}
   <script src="{{asset('CSS-JS/TimePicki-master/js/timepicki.js')}}"></script>
   <script src="{{asset('CSS-JS/jQueryFiler/js/jquery.filer.min.js')}}"></script>
   <script src="{{asset('CSS-JS/slim/slim/slim.kickstart.js')}}"></script>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro preReady() %}

var placeSearch, autocomplete, target;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};


[...]

$(".lat").val(place.geometry.location.lat());
$(".lng").val(place.geometry.location.lng());
}
{% endmacro %}
```

What point did I miss ?

Thanks a lot, in advance !

Comment: My guess is that block preReady is not defined in parent template.
Try to remove {{parent()}} from preReady block. Does it help?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help, because I do have a preReady block in the parent template. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I've been using another method, have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the macro file in every file where you are going to use it. It doesn't matter if the file of the template is already importing it, you still need to import it manually.

On top of file add:

```
{% import "your_macro_file.ext" as common %}
```

this way you can use:

```
common.CSSexterne()
```